# Firebase: updating issue

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database with the following structure:

[image: databse structure]

I need to update the order's amount child value and then add a new child `updatedAt` which will have the timestamp of this update.
I use an object of which contains the paths that I want to update and then call `ref.update(dataToBeUpdated)`.

The problem is that the children that I didn't update as the timestamp is removed when I call `update()` .. it acts like I rewrite the order node and not editing some of its children.. any help?

UPDATE :
Here is how the code looks like :
var dataToUpdate = { [orderPath] : { 'amount': newAmount, 'updatedAt': firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP } } return ref.update(dataToUpdate)

Comment: may you provide more code snap, as for example, how you set the values, and update child, the value of `ref` and so on.

Comment: var dataToUpdate = {
[orderPath] : {
        'amount': newAmount,
       
        'updatedAt': firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
  }
}
return ref.update(dataToUpdate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's over writing your data, most likely because you aren't providing the full-path. For example if you are only providing `ref.child("postID").update(update)` you're overwriting everything under that "postID". I can't really provide an exact solution without seeing your data and code. If you update your post I can provide additional details, but for now try this: `ref.child("amount").update(newAmount)` and `ref.child("updatedAt").update(newTimestamp)`

The first one should overwrite the old amount and the second one should add the child updatedAt with your timestamp.

Another way would be to download all the existing data for that order update it locally and then re-upload the whole thing.

Take a look at the  [update documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

Comment: then what is the difference between update and set .. i think they will both do the same according to your explanation @DoesData